# TypeScript - Visual Studio 2015 does not know about types in other files

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I started using TypeScript in my ASP.Net MVC project.
My filestructure looks like this:

```
Project
|-ts 
| |- Common
| | |-AppSettings.ts
| |-Components
| | |-DeleteModal.ts
```

**AppSetttings.ts** contains a class with some static properties representing global application constants:

```
namespace Ls.Common {
    export class AppSettings {
        public static readonly DeleteMethod = 'DELETE';
    }
}
```

**DeleteModal.ts** uses Ls.Common.AppSettings.DeleteMethod value as type for making an ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: Ls.Common.AppSettings.DeleteMethod,
    url: this.config.deleteUrl,
    async: true
})
.done((data) => {
    // Display result
});
```

Visual Studio displays the following error in DeleteModal.ts:

*Property 'AppSettings' does not exist on type 'typeof Common'.*

Building the TS files using gulp works and creats the expected output.
How can I make Visual Studio know about types in other TS files (inside of the same project)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a refrence in *DeleteModal.ts* solved the problem:

```
/// <reference path="../common/appsettings.ts" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Visual Studio didn't include the file in the analysis. Since gulp  works, it's likely that gulp is using the correct `tsconfig.json` and the Visual Studio is not.

It's rather often that typescript configuration is included in the `.csproj`, and that configuration will override what is in `tsconfig.json` by default.

Please check if you having different configuration in different place mentioned above. The one in `csproj` looks like this

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>amd</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>True</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    ....
</PropertyGroup>
```